# Playwright Cucumber Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 5000 ms

Tags: javascript, cucumber, playwright

function timed out, browser not launching. I'm fairly new to JavaScript and couldn't resolve the issue

```
> Launch Browser
> VError: a BeforeAll hook errored, process exiting: setup\hooks.js:12: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 5000 milliseconds
> at Runtime.runTestRunHooks (D:\Playwright_CCO Test Automation Projects\copas-cco-ui-automation_cucumber\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\lib\runtime\run_test_run_hooks.js:23:23)
> at async Runtime.start (D:\Playwright_CCO Test Automation Projects\copas-cco-ui-automation_cucumber\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\lib\runtime\index.js:53:9)
> at async runCucumber (D:\Playwright_CCO Test Automation Projects\copas-cco-ui-automation_cucumber\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\lib\api\run_cucumber.js:106:21)
> at async Cli.run (D:\Playwright_CCO Test Automation Projects\copas-cco-ui-automation_cucumber\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\lib\cli\index.js:51:29)
> at async Object.run [as default] (D:\Playwright_CCO Test Automation Projects\copas-cco-ui-automation_cucumber\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\lib\cli\run.js:30:18)
> caused by: Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 5000 milliseconds
> at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\Playwright_CCO Test Automation Projects\copas-cco-ui-automation_cucumber\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\lib\time.js:54:20)
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
> at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
```

I have setDefaultTimeout in before hooks, then in the steps file {timeout: 60 * 1000} neither of the solutions worked. Running out of ideas.

```
> const playwright = require('playwright')
> const { Before, After, BeforeAll, AfterAll } = require('@cucumber/cucumber')> 
> 
> To launch the browser before all the scenarios
> BeforeAll(async () => {
> console.log('Launch Browser')
> //Giving browser- Chromium and headed mode
> global.browser = await playwright['chromium'].launch({ headless: false,
setDefaultTimeout:  60 * 1000
})
>     
> console.log('before all executed')
>   })
> 
> AfterAll(async () => {
> console.log("Close Browser");
> await global.browser.close();
> });
> 
> Before(async () => {
> console.log("Create new context and page")
> global.context = await global.browser.newContext();
> global.page = await global.context.newPage();
> });
> 
> After(async () => {
> console.log("Close context and page");
> await global.page.close();
> await global.context.close();
> });
```

Comment: I've also tried creating a TS project with cucumber and resulted in same error. Two different instructors.. sum1 shed some light here pls

Comment: so i got the solution working in TS but this doesnt work for JS i.e. import { Given, When, Then, setDefaultTimeout } from "@cucumber/cucumber";
setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000 * 2)

Comment: Please read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because **setDefaultTimeout** of Playwright is not related to Cucumber timeouts.

Can you use `@playwright/test` framework instead?
It will allow you to use native *it/test/describe/before/after* with timeouts that work